# React Native SDK returns error code 17 while ceating a channel but node library works fine

Tags: react-native

On trying to create a channel using the react Native SDK, I get the following error

```
Error: StreamChat error code 17: GetOrCreateChannel failed with error: "User '12345' with roles ['user', 'channel_member'] from teams ['red', '7fdfce50-asdd-ddsaa-976a', '02asdadsa-8ddsadad-adadasdad-7-ca3'] cannot access resource in scope 'messaging' because requested resource does not belong to any team"
```

But when I try to create a channel using the node library, it works perfectly fine.. any ideas why this is happening?

Answer (score 0):

That error in our case was caused by multitenancy, which may or may not be your issue. The code below works if you're running an app with multitenancy:

```
  const channel = client.channel("messaging", `someuniquestring`, {
     team: "Team Name",
     members: [memberId1, memberId2],
  });

  await channel.watch();
```